# Questioning a calculation in Kapusta / Infinite entropy of a Fermi gas?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, regularization, quantum-statistics, thermal-field-theory

I am going through Kapusta's calculation of the free energy of a Fermi gas, and I find one of his steps dubious (and if I'm right, it would mean the free energy of a Fermi gas is either infinite or requires regularization).

He starts from

$$\tag{2.95} \label{2.95} 
\ln Z=\sum_n \sum_{\mathbf{p}}\left\{\ln \left[\beta^2\left(\omega_n^2(\omega-\mu)^2\right)\right]+\ln \left[\beta^2\left(\omega_n^2(\omega+\mu)^2\right)\right]\right\},$$

which I think is missing $+$ signs between the $\omega_n^2$'s and the $(\omega\pm\mu)$'s. (See the previous formulas in Kapusta to verify that this is intended; note also that as written, the units do not work out. This mistake is not the subject of this post.) He then manipulates the arguments of the logarithms as follows,

$$\tag{2.96} \label{2.96}
\ln \left[(2 n+1)^2 \pi^2+\beta^2(\omega \pm \mu)^2\right]=\int_1^{\beta^2(\omega \pm \mu)^2} \frac{d \theta^2}{\theta^2+(2 n+1)^2 \pi^2}
+\ln[1+(2n+1)^2\pi^2],$$

and then performs the Matsubara sum on the first term in \ref{2.96}. (He provides a few more formulas for this.) Of course there is an issue with the second term in \ref{2.96} because it diverges under the sum. However, Kapusta justifies ignoring this term because it is "independent of $\beta$ and $\mu$," and concludes

$$\tag{2.99} \label{2.99}
\ln Z=2 V \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3}\left[\beta \omega+\ln \left(1+\mathrm{e}^{-\beta(\omega-\mu)}\right)+\ln \left(1+\mathrm{e}^{-\beta(\omega+\mu)}\right)\right].$$

---

I would almost agree, except that the free energy is proportional to $T\ln Z$, not just $\ln Z$. So it appears the term being neglected isn't really independent of $T$, and we are in fact omitting an infinite term that is linear in $T$. This wouldn't affect several quantities (e.g., pressure), but it should affect the entropy, $S=(\partial/\partial T)(T\ln Z)$, which in fact becomes infinite.

**So is the entropy of an ideal Fermi gas infinite? Or am I making a mistake? Or is Kapusta making a mistake?**

Comment: The neglected term is independent of $T$ and $\mu$, but does depend linearly on $V$, so call it $\alpha V$, where $\alpha$ is independent of $T$, $\mu$, and $V$. This leads to $S=V\alpha + S_K$ and $P=T\alpha + P_K$ and $E=E_K$ and $N=N_K$, where the terms with the subscript $K$ are what you would find with Kapusta's neglection. Seems like we should have $\alpha=0$, but I haven't been able to look at it closely...

Comment: @hft How does it wind up being overall independent of $T$, given that there is an infinite constant term in $\ln Z$ multiplying a factor of $T$ in $T \ln Z$?

Comment: I mean the neglected term in $\ln(Z)$ is independent of $T$ and $\mu$: $\ln(Z) = \alpha V + \ln(Z_K)$. So, for example $\ln(Z)=\beta P V = \alpha V + \beta P_K V$.